# Can't seem to get a mask working in Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to create an SVG animation using Snap.svg.

Everytime I try to apply a mask, I just see nothing.

The code is relatively straightforward (and works perfectly in the examples):

```
var open = s.select('.open');
var circle = s.select('.circle').attr({mask:open});
```

[Here's the whole example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXJxYA). I've commented out the code that should apply the mask so you can get an idea of what I'm going for.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by the fact that the mask is affected by both the `transform` on your iris circle (`.circle`), **and** its own transform.  In other words, the transform is being applied twice.

There are a number of solutions.  One would be to remove the transform attribute from your mask path (`.open`).

You also need to give your mask element a fill. If it doesn't have a fill, nothing will show up. The reason is that in masks, black (or none/transparent) corresponds to transparency in the mask, and white corresponds to opaque. Colours in between result in translucent areas.

```js
var s = Snap('#eye');

var open = s.select('.open');
var circle = s.select('.circle')
              .attr({mask:open});

function closeEye() {
    open.animate({ d: "M317.44,135.56s-3,7.41-14,7.41c-10.23,0-13.39-7.44-13.39-7.44s3.16,7.44,13.39,7.44C314.44,143,317.44,135.56,317.44,135.56Z" }, 200, mina.easeinout,openEye);
}

function openEye() {
  console.log('callback fired');
  open.animate({ d: "M317.44,135.56s-3-7.59-14-7.59c-10.23,0-13.39,7.56-13.39,7.56s3.16,7.44,13.39,7.44C314.44,143,317.44,135.56,317.44,135.56Z" }, 200, mina.easeinout);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  closeEye();  
   $('#eye').mouseenter( function() {
  closeEye();  
    console.log('hovered');
   });
});
```

```css
.circle, .open {
 stroke-width: 1px;
 stroke-linecap: rounded;
 stroke:black;
 fill: none;
}
.open {
 fill: white;
}

.svg-wrapper {
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.3.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="svg-wrapper">
<svg id="eye" viewBox="0 0 28.5 16">
<defs></defs>
  
<path class="circle" d="M309.56,135.47a5.82,5.82,0,1,1-5.82-5.82A5.82,5.82,0,0,1,309.56,135.47Z" transform="translate(-289.48 -127.47)"/>

<path class="open" d="M317.44,135.56s-3-7.59-14-7.59c-10.23,0-13.39,7.56-13.39,7.56s3.16,7.44,13.39,7.44C314.44,143,317.44,135.56,317.44,135.56Z"/>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh that's so great. It does make sense, because the mask essentially becomes a nested element. Thank you!

Comment: I also saw you added `fill:white` to both paths. I don't really understand why that's necessary but it works!

Comment: Only the mask actually needed to be white. I've updated my answer to explain why.